# Несколько вопросов по командной работе в git над сайтом

Tags: git, веб-программирование

Недавно усторился на новую работу, до этого с git-ом особо не работал — делал всё в одиночку. Нас в команде трое: 2 программиста и один верстальщик.
Прочитал git-scm, githowto всё равно остались, возможно глупые, вопросы:

1) Если я пишу код в windows, а боевой сервер на nix, то ставить core.autocrlf true — верно?

2) Обязательно ли Feature, Hotfix-бранчи пушить на сервер при условии что 
над каждой такой веткой работает 1 программист? 
Мои мысли: создаю такой бранч локально от develop, работаю, ребейсю (или лучше merge/потом удалить ветку???) с локальной develop веткой, пушу и пулю её уже.

3) Всякие подготовительные релизные работы (поменять debug define с true на false, очистить кеш, сжать css,js) надо делать отдельным коммитом в релизной ветке или же
это выходит за рамки git-а?

4) Я правильно понимаю что на боевом сервере git-а быть не должно?

5) git pull --rebase или git pull использовать чтобы просто обновить изменения сделанных другими программистами в у себя в ветке? Если ли существенная разница кроме более ветвистой истории?

Comment: Половина вопросов отпадет, когда начнете юзать PhpStorm - все делается через gui. Чтобы понять как шторм сделал то или иное действие - откройте лог в нижней панели. По остальным моментам все есть в git-scm, посмотрите внимательнее

Comment: Вредный совет. Gui нужно использоваться максимум что бы посмотреть состояние, но не более.  Более того, gui не решает вышеуказанные вопросы. Большинство подобный программ все равно спрашивают - ребейзить или мержить (или может форсированно запушим?).

Comment: @mihdan да я и так юзаю phpstorm и делаю update project и commit changes. Просто хотелось более подробно во всем разобраться.

Comment: Вопрос закрыли, потому что на самом деле тут 5 разных вопросов. Лучше задавать их отдельно, потому что 1) все вместе плохо гуглятся, 2) на все сразу сложно дать развёрнутые ответы. 3) непонятно, для чего именно сработал принятый ответ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1) Если я пишу код в windows, а боевой сервер на nix, то ставить core.autocrlf true — верно?

настройте свой редактор так, что бы у него были "правильные" переводы строк (линуксовые). Тогда ничего не нужно будет специально изменять. Либо используйте виндовые переводы строки и выберите настройки по умолчанию (туда, если я правильно помню, как раз и входит autocrlf=true). Больше почитать можно [здесь](http://jenyay.net/Git/Autocrlf).

> 2) Обязательно ли Feature, Hotfix-бранчи пушить на сервер

желательно, если хочется поработать из дому, а не только на работе. Также это очень удобно - допустим, приболел или задержался в пробке - коллега может взять ветку и посмотреть, применить, доработать. А может и винт посыпаться. Если ветка запушена - все будет хорошо.

> ребейсю (или лучше merge/потом удалить ветку???)

это исключительно вопрос предпочтений и договоренностей.

> Всякие подготовительные релизные работы (поменять debug define с true на false, очистить кеш, сжать css,js)

либо держите две ветки (для дебага и для релиза, их часто так и называют - develop и release/rc/master), либо, что более правильно - сделайте скрипт деплоя - специальный скрипт, который будет сорцы проверять, упаковывать/процессить и куда нужно заливать.

> 4) Я правильно понимаю что на боевом сервере git-а быть не должно?

git может быть, а вот использоваться его для ленивого деплоя (то есть, простым pull) - не стоит. Эту ошибку делают многие и потом имеют что делать:)

> 5) git pull --rebase или git pull использовать чтобы просто обновить изменения

к сожалению, Линус не решил этот вопрос и это приводит к постоянным религиозным войнам. Мое лично мнение - та, команда, которая короче, та и правильнее:)

Comment: Большое спасибо за подробный ответ. Половина вопросов отпали. Осталось парочку:

Comment: 1) "сделайте скрипт деплоя - специальный скрипт, " - а не подскажите если ты готовые решения по деплою/сжатию? Я так понимаю скрипт деплоя должен запускаться автоматом после коммита в релизную ветку?

Comment: 2) чем плох git pull на боевом сервере? дело в том, что до моего прихода там так и использовалось. Хочу в понедельник аргументировать.

Comment: Вряд ли подобный универсальный скрипт может существовать - каждый сайт понемножку уникальный. Но в целом все сводиться к копированию файлов и подсовыванию правильный конфигов.
Запускать подобный скрипт после каждого коммита в релиз я бы не рекомендовал. Мало чего там будет закоммичено и когда. А вот на какой-нибудь тестовый сервер -это может быть хорошей идеей.
Почему не нужно держать гит на проде? ну кроме того, что под это требуются дополнительное место, в мире было много "epic fail" с этим. Вот [как может быть с svn](https://habrahabr.ru/post/70330/). Точно такое же может случиться  в git